# android:background selectableItemBackground is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to use `selectableItemBackground` in `recyclerview`, I test a simple demo, it's working.

Here is layout and style:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Style:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

When I test another project, it doesn't work, I'm looking for some solutions, one of solutions say may be style.

But the solution style was `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, i used it too.

Here is my project layout, is anyone can tell me why?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pink_circle" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Style:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The animation part of background requires your element to be clickable. Set `android:clickable="true"`.

Comment: thank you @Marius Kaunietis,it figure out my problem,I did not expect these simple, truly thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, best practice is to also add `android:focusable="true"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look, I think it should help: https://yq.aliyun.com/articles/12407

Comment: I read it before,but not found the answer at that moment. I solve my problem now,thanks for your link @juemuren4449

Comment: Please, post the actual solution and not just a link. Thanks.